# Force a Java Tooltip to Appear

Tags: java, tooltip

Given a `JTextField` (or any `JComponent` for that matter), how would one go about forcing that component's designated tooltip to appear, without any direct input event from the user? In other words, why is there no `JComponent.setTooltipVisible(boolean)`?

Comment: You mean you wish for the tooltip to be continuously visible?  Because that's not what tooltips are used for...

Answer (score 6):

The only way (besides creating your own Tooltip window) I've found is to emmulate the CTRL+F1 keystroke on focus:

```
new FocusAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(e.getComponent(), KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), InputEvent.CTRL_MASK,
                    KeyEvent.VK_F1, KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);
            e.getComponent().dispatchEvent(ke);
        }
        catch (Throwable e1)
        {e1.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the tooltip will disappear as soon as you move your mouse (outside of the component) or after a delay (see `ToolTipManager.setDismissDelay`).

Comment: +1, my original suggestion was based on the F1 key invoking the "postTip" Action. I thought it was cleaner to invoke the Action directly rather than dispatch the KeyEvent. Not sure why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: tooltips are really badly implemented in java imo. very inflexible. that such hacks are necessary (and hardly achieve what is needed) show the api is lacking.

Comment: Is Ctrl+F1 platform independent?  Should I expect it to work on a Mac the same as Windows?

Comment: quite possibly not! post your solution if you find one... @NickMiller

Answer (score 5):

You need to invoke the default Action to show the tooltip. For example to show a tooltip when a component gains focus you can add the following FocusListener to the component:

```
FocusAdapter focusAdapter = new FocusAdapter()
{
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();
        Action toolTipAction = component.getActionMap().get("postTip");

        if (toolTipAction != null)
        {
            ActionEvent postTip = new ActionEvent(component, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
            toolTipAction.actionPerformed( postTip );
        }

    }
};
```

Edit:

The above code doesn't seem to work anymore. Another approach is dispatch a MouseEvent to the component:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PostTipSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public PostTipSSCCE()
    {
        FocusAdapter fa = new FocusAdapter()
        {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
                JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();

                MouseEvent phantom = new MouseEvent(
                    component,
                    MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    0,
                    10,
                    10,
                    0,
                    false);

                ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().mouseMoved(phantom);
            }
        };

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setToolTipText("button tool tip");
        button.addFocusListener( fa );
        add( button );

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.setToolTipText("text field tool tip");
        textField.addFocusListener( fa );
        add( textField );

        JCheckBox checkBox =  new JCheckBox("CheckBox");
        checkBox.setToolTipText("checkbox tool tip");
        checkBox.addFocusListener( fa );
        add( checkBox );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PostTipSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(new PostTipSSCCE()) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This approach will result in a slight delay before the tooltip is displayed as it simulated the mouse entering the component. For immediate display of the tooltip you can use pstanton's solution.

Comment: Note that with this code, the position of the tooltip is not specified and will most likely not be under the mouse cursor

Comment: toolTipAction is null for my JButton. Why is that?

Comment: this doesn't work, `component.getActionMap().get("postTip");` returns null for `JTextField`

Comment: @pstanton, hmmm, it returns null for all components now. Anyway, I provided an alternative suggestion.

Comment: You can use `TooltipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay()` to show the tooltip instantly with a value of 0.

Comment: @AdrienClerc, that assumes the user is hovering the mouse over the component which was not the requirement of this question.

Answer (score 2):

For me works the similar version stated above (instead of Timer I used SwingUtilities and invokeLater approach):

```
private void showTooltip(Component component)
{
    final ToolTipManager ttm = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
    final int oldDelay = ttm.getInitialDelay();
    ttm.setInitialDelay(0);
    ttm.mouseMoved(new MouseEvent(component, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, // X-Y of the mouse for the tool tip
            0, false));
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            ttm.setInitialDelay(oldDelay);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `ToolTipManager`, set the initial delay to 0 and send it an event. Don't forget to restore the values afterwards.

```
private void displayToolTip()
{
    final ToolTipManager ttm = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
    final MouseEvent event = new MouseEvent(this, 0, 0, 0,
                                            0, 0, // X-Y of the mouse for the tool tip
                                            0, false);
    final int oldDelay = ttm.getInitialDelay();
    final String oldText = textPane.getToolTipText(event);
    textPane.setToolTipText("<html><a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a></html>!");
    ttm.setInitialDelay(0);
    ttm.setDismissDelay(1000);
    ttm.mouseMoved(event);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ttm.setInitialDelay(oldDelay);
            textPane.setToolTipText(oldText);
        }
    }, ttm.getDismissDelay());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `ToolTip`, but you can use a balloon tip:
http://timmolderez.be/balloontip/doku.php

It is showing just on call and feels better in some moments then Default `ToolTip`

Comment: Note that unlike tooltips, these balloons can't exit the window containing the targeted component.