# How can i get mouse cursor value in Java Chart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I try to get mouse cursor values in Java Chart. I have two variables on Y axis and I have one variable on X axis. My y axis variables looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6fna.png) and I use crosshair to get the values of axis. My code is attached below.

```
@Override
public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event){
  ChartEntity chartEntity = event.getEntity();
  if(chartEntity instanceof XYItemEntity)
  {
     XYItemEntity xyItemEntity = (XYItemEntity) chartEntity;
     XYDataset xyDataSet = xyItemEntity.getDataset();
     this.xCrosshair.setValue(xyDataSet.getXValue(xyItemEntity.getSeriesIndex(), 
     xyItemEntity.getItem()));
     this.yCrosshair.setValue(xyDataSet.getYValue(xyItemEntity.getSeriesIndex(), 
     xyItemEntity.getItem()));

  }
```

When I put my mouse to values of temperature I can get these values but when I put my values of power, I can't get the values. Here is the example of temperature values :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y24VQ.png) As you can see I got temperature value 19.215 and here is the example of power :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEx0s.png) I can't get the value. How can I get rid of this problem and how can I get all values of two axis?

Comment: A similar issue is examined in a series of questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64266993/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64217855/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64201748/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64148281/230513).

Comment: You can look up the power and display it with temperature in your implementation of `generateLabel()`, shown in the examples cited.