# How can I find the name of axis in multiple range axis JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, charts, jlabel, jfreechart

I have 3 variables in Y axis and I am trying to get the name of the axis according to value which I look for.

[image].

Variables are attached here. I can get the value of the variable with label, but I can't get the name of variable.

[image].

I want to write the name of the variable in front of the label. How can I find it? My code looks like:

```
public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event){
   ChartEntity chartEntity = event.getEntity();
   if ( chartEntity instanceof XYItemEntity) {
      XYItemEntity xyItemEntity = (XYItemEntity) chartEntity;
      XYDataSet xyDataSet = xyItemEntity.getDataset();

      double xValue = xyDataSet .getXValue(xyItemEntity.getSeriesIndex(), xyItemEntity.getItem());
      double yValue = xyDataSet .getYValue(xyItemEntity.getSeriesIndex(), xyItemEntity.getItem());

      this.xCrosshair.setValue(xValue);
      this.yCrosshair.setValue(yValue);


      label.setText(String.format("%.2f, yValue));
      label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, at least to me. Please consider giving us a more and clear explanation of your code and your problem.

Comment: The first picture is about the axis of Y, and the second picture is the value of one of these axis. I can get the value of the axis but I can't get the variable name of the axis. How can I get it? When I click on the graph line on the chart, I want to get the X and Y axises labels.

Comment: See also [How can I get mouse cursor value in Java Chart?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71018827/230513)

Answer (score 1):

An [`XYPlot`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) has methods to access the axes used to construct the chart. Starting from this complete, two-axis [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513), the following loop prints the names of the range axes to the console:

```
for (int i = 0; i < plot.getRangeAxisCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(plot.getRangeAxis(i).getLabel());
}
```

Console:

```
Meters
Feet
```

[image]